# How to minimize the minimum mean square error of this difference

Tags: optimization, mean-square-error

I am trying to minimize the mean square error. More precisely, I am trying to minimize the following optimization problem

$$\arg \min _{{\bf w}_1, {\bf w}_2} \mathbb{E} \left[ \|{\bf s} - {\bf Wy}\|^2 \right]$$
$${\bf W} = \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf w}_1       &{\bf 0 } \\
    {\bf 0 }       & {\bf w}_2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where ${\bf W}$ is a $2\times N$ matrix and where ${\bf w_i}$ is a $1\times N/2$ for $i\in[1:2]$ and ${\bf 0}$ is $1\times N/2$ vector while ${\bf s}$ is 2 $\times $ 1 and ${\bf y}$ is $N \times 1$ vectors.

Any hints or ideas on finding the minimizing vectors of this problem?

It is also given that

$${\bf y = A F s + z}$$ where ${\bf A}$ is $N\times N$ matrix while

$${\bf F} = \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf f_1}       &{\bf 0} \\
    {\bf 0}       & {\bf f_2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where ${\bf f_i}$ are $N/2\times 1$ vector and ${\bf Z}$ is $N\times 1$ vector

I am thinking of starting to start the solution as following
$$\arg\min _{\bf{w_1},\bf{w_2}}\mathbb{E} \,\,[[{\bf s} - {\bf Wy}]^H[{\bf s} - {\bf Wy}]]$$

But I assume given the specific block diagonal structure of matrix ${\bf W}$ and ${\bf F}$ it should be easier to solve ...

Thanks

Comment: There must be something wrong with the dimensions. $\mathbf W$ is a $2\times N$-matrix and $\mathbf y$ is a $2\times 1$-vector, Then $\mathbf{ Wy}$ is not possible.

Comment: sorry had typo thanks

Comment: I hope I´m not wrong, but it seems very similar to linear regression. Here it is $(s-Wy)'(s-Wy)=(s'-y'W')(s-Wy)=s's-s'Wy-y'W's-y'W'Wy$ But at linear regression it is optimized w.r.t $y$, not $W$. But I think it  wouldn´t be bad to have a look on this subject.

Comment: thnk you for the reference

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to find the non random matrix $W$ and hence its elements are not boldface in my solution. $\mathbf s$ and $\mathbf y$ are random vectors, hence they are boldface. First let me write the matrix ${W} 
= \begin{bmatrix}
    {w_{1}^*}       &{ 0 } \\
    { 0 }       & { w_{2}^* }
\end{bmatrix}
$
where $*$ denotes the hermitian operation. Now all lower case vectors are column vectors.
This problem can be restated as
$\arg \min _{{w_1},{w_2}}\mathbb{E} \,\,\left[\left\Vert\begin{bmatrix}
    \bf s_1^* \\
    \bf s_{2}^*
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf y_{1}^*}       &{\bf 0 } \\
    {\bf 0 }       & {\bf y_{2}^* }
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
     w_1 \\
     w_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\right\Vert^2\right] $.
After this, the problem decouples to solving for $w_1$ and $w_2$. For eg. for $w_1$, we need to minimize $J =\mathbb E[ ||\mathbf s_1^* - \mathbf y_1^* w_1||^2]$.
Just expand the inside argument and differentiate w.r.t. $w_1^*$ and put the gradient to $0$. We get the solution for $w_1$ as
$\mathbb E [\mathbf y_1 \mathbf y_1^*] w_1 = \mathbb E [\mathbf y_1^* \mathbf s_1^*]$.
Now, assuming you can find the correlation matrix of $\mathbf y_1$ and it is invertible, and the cross correlation between $\mathbf y_1$ and $\mathbf s_1$, you can find $w_1$. Similarly, you can solve for $w_2$.

Comment: i am not sure... wht how did you decompose vector y?

Comment: The Nx1 vector $\mathbf y$ is split into two vectors $\mathbf y_1$ and $\mathbf y_2$ each N/2 x1, stacked on top of each other. Hope that clears the confusion.